# Проверка наличия ip в "черных" списках

Tags: ip

Интересуют открытые сервисы по проверке наличия ip в "черных" списках. Так как проверка планируется программная, то и сервис должен быть без искусственных задержек (в пару сек.) и каптч. Конечно, хотелось бы, чтобы проверка шла по актуальным спискам (и сервис проводил проверку по нескольким спискам, а не по одному). Есть ли такой?

Comment: А что такое "черные списки" для ip адресов?

Comment: @KoVadim Сарказм? Ну вроде репутация позволяет исправить вопрос/тему в соответствии с правильным пониманием вопроса представителями сообщества...

Comment: Черные списки могут быть по разным критериям. Например в фильтрации спама активно используются различные RBL листы. В том числе по ip с которых часто идет спам, есть листы проверки на открытые прокси и неправильно настроенные почтовые релеи и много другое. RBL проверки осуществляются через DNS

Comment: а я не знаю, что Вы имеете ввиду под "черными списками".  Почему то мне кажется, что это как то связано с роскомнадзором, но она не имеет на меня влияния.

Comment: @Mike интересуют ip, с которых 1) может приходить спам; 2) атакуют сервера.

Comment: читаете https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL после чего в гугле вбиваете скажем "RBL листы" и/или "RBL list" и далее модифицируете запросы к гуглу по своему усмотрению. После чего берете готовые программы проверки и/или пишете свой. резолв адресов по DNS делается элементарно. главное много запросов паралельно рассылать, что бы укладываться в пару секунд

Comment: @Mike Спасибо. Я умею пользоваться гуглом. Если на то пошло, то подобный ответ можете давать всем пользователям, оставляющим вопросы на данном сайте. Или Вы так и поступаете? Вы думаете, что я не гуглил? Так в вопросе написал (повторюсь для Вас), что интересует сервис без искусственных задержек и каптч. Как Вы думаете, почему я заострил на этом внимание? Наверное, по результатом того самого гугления.

Comment: @Mike писать буду свою программку. В детстве у меня не было велосипеда. Поэтому, когда вырос, очень люблю их создавать.

Comment: @Softinaria Тогда вопрос что вы называете "сервисом". Тем более что решили писать свою программу. При параллельной рассылке DNS запросов по списку RBL листов вполне уложитесь в 2 сек. И никаких капч службы DNS не подразумевают. Вы хотите один готовый сервис - не найдете. Каждый сам для себя решает каке списки использовать

Comment: @Mike Я Вас понял... Чего-то более-менее общего не будет. Предлагаете стучаться по отдельности на десятки серверов :(

Comment: @Softinaria Для начала можете даже из командной строки попробовать. Берем скажем ip 79.101.32.5. переворачивем его задом наперед (так принято в DNS): 5.32.101.79 и делаем запрос: `nslookup 5.32.101.79.bb.barracudacentral.org` получаем ответ `127.0.0.2` - все, значит он в этом списке. Заметьте "Стучатся" - это слишком громко сказано, один вызов функции gethostbyname, несколько UDP пакетов прошедших по сети ... Конечно надо использовать не gethostbyname а какие нибудь библиотечки, которые рассылают запросы в паралель

Comment: @Mike да из командной я уже проверял и пробовал. Это я все понимаю. Просто хотелось какой-то более общий сервис, на который я бы обратился примерно также и получил ответ. Т.е. вместо обращения к сотне серверов хотелось бы обращаться к одному-двум.

Comment: @Softinaria Т.е. хотите переложить рассылку запросов на какой то сервис, который тупо сделает это за вас (ибо каких то общих баз на сколько я знаю никто не ведет, все почтовые фильтры сами расылают запросы). По задержкам особо не выиграете. И кстати некий "общий" сервис довольно спорное решение, даже если бы он был. Потому как некоторые листы протухают, причем были случаи когда их владельцы обозлялись на весь мир и на любые запросы возвращали 127.0.0.2, в итоге вся почта проверямая по таким спискам улетала в спам. И надо постоянно следить за ситуацией и удалять такие списки из проверок

Comment: @Mike Да. Именно так. Хотелось бы переложить рассылку на какой-то сервис. В моем понимании, подобные сервисы именно и занимаются тем, что ищут актуальные листы, удаляют протухшие... В общем, следят за этим делом, обновляют списки. Да и в случае падения такого сервиса, поменять один адрес мне не составило бы труда, чем выполнять эту работу по обновлению списков. И такие сервисы в принципе есть, но, как я уже указывал выше, или с каптчей или с задержкой.

Comment: @Softinaria Лично я таким сервисам не верю. Откуда я знаю как внимательно владелец смотрит за листами. Почему работа моей почтовой системы должна зависеть от действий некого третьего лица. Если я проверяю по паре десятков листов сам, то я сам расставляю рейтинги в зависимости от моего опыта и доверия конкретным листам. И один лист в итоге имеет небольшое значение для итогового вердикта. Решение принимается только по сумме множества проверок. А спец. сервис даст вам скорее всего только итоговый свой вердикт и скорее всего даст "положительно" даже при сработке единственного листа

Comment: @Mike Ну да. С этим я соглашусь, что сервис выдаст вердикт при сработке единственного листа. Конечно же это не всегда будет "гуд". Вопрос же доверия - это уже вопрос, выходящий за рамки рассматриваемого. Но Есть сервисы, работающие в этой сфере годами и имеющие какую-никакую репутацию. Вряд ли они невнимательно будут относиться к тому, во что вложили свой многолетний труд. А Ваш подход более чем жизнеспособен. Возможно, и я к этому приду сейчас, если не найдется иного ответа.